# JSON Object Containing Array To ArrayList<POJO> With GSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, gson

I am new to JSON and GSON, and I am taking a JSON feed from an input stream, and put it into an array list of custom objects. The JSON feed contains a single object, which contains an array of more objects. It looks something like this:

```
{ "container":[
    {"item_1":"item one"},
    {"item_2":"item two"},
    {"item_3":"item three"}
]}
```

I am currently using a `TypeToken` with a `Map` to obtain the container object along with the list of objects as an array list of custom objects. Like so:

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

Type listType = new TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<Item>>>(){}.getType();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Map<String, ArrayList<Item>> treeMap = gson.fromJson(input, listType);
ArrayList<Item> objects = treeMap.get("container");

input.close();
```

I would like to know if there is a way to skip the step of creating a `Map<String, ArrayList<Item>>`, and go directly from the input stream to an `ArrayList<Item>` using GSON. Just to consolidate my code, creating a map seems like an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define a wrapper type which has a `container` property, and then deserialize the JSON to that type instead of to a `Map`.

```
public static class Wrapper {
    public List<Item> container;
}

Wrapper wrapper = gson.fromJson(input, Wrapper.class);
List<Item> objects = wrapper.container;
```

Comment: Would this approach be any more efficient? It essentially gets rid of the need for a `TypeToken`, but you need to create another class. It looks like a good alternative, but not exactly what I was hoping for.